# Bitcoin.conf connect command

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, nodes, bitcoin.conf, peer-discovery

When configuring the `bitcoin.conf` file, what should you put in `connect=`?  There are IP addresses listed here, so I removed the `#` sign and left them as is.  I also entered my WAN address and my local IP address with the forwarded port a separate time.  What should I enter and how will I know it is working correctly?

Comment: Trusted nodes only. This is one more security precaution for payment gateways and apps that deal with significant funds but also for everyone who wants to make sure they won't establish a p2p connection with a malicious node. It could become a problem if your trusted nodes aren't available at times, though.

Comment: Where does one verify which nodes are trusted and which not?  Should I remove the # sign and enter my WAN and local IP, or should I leave the defaults?  Sorry, I realize that my intermediate command line and tcp/ip knowledge may make this question look ridiculous, but I just wanted to confirm.  Thanks, oemb1905.

Comment: Think should help: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes

Comment: That was helpful.  However, how come the defaults then are not listed on the trusted nodes wiki?  The default lists 69.164.218.197 and 10.0.0.2:8333 ... whose nodes are those?

Comment: `69.164.218.197` was the address of an old bitcoin Faucet that doesn't exist anymore but back then it was a highly active node due to its nature and now only serves as a configuration example.

Comment: So then I should replace that entry with one of the nodes listed on the page you referred me to?

Comment: No, if you have just started getting familiar with the protocol you shouldn't be adding them manually, leave this for a bit later on when you will be able to define your own `trusted nodes` list. In a totally trust-less network it's all about who YOU trust and not who you "should" trust.